# Python list of dictionary append value to different keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have this list with dictionaries:

```
In [5]: m

Out[5]: [{0: ['a', 'b'], 1: '1', 2: '2'},
         {0: ['a', 'b'], 1: '3', 2: '4'},
         {0: ['xx', 'yy'], 1: '100', 2: '200'},
         {0: ['xx', 'yy'], 1: '300', 2: '400'}]
```

I do this:

```
In [6]: r = defaultdict(list)

In [7]: for k, v in ((k, v) for row in m for k, v in row.iteritems()):
            r[k].append(v)
```

And it return:

```
In [8]: r
Out[8]: defaultdict(list,
        {0: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['xx', 'yy'], ['xx', 'yy']],
         1: ['1', '3', '100', '300'],
         2: ['2', '4', '200', '400']})
```

But I want other thing, like this:

```
        {0: ['a', 'b'],
         1: ['1', '3'],
         2: ['2', '4']}, 

        {0: ['xx', 'yy'],
         1: ['100', '300'],
         2: ['200', '400']}
```

How can i do this? I want to take the same value in the key 0 and collect them all other values found in other keys.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the transformation you're going for. Can you describe step by step how to start with what you have and end up with what you want? Not only will it probably get you better help, it might even 'click' how to do it yourself.

Comment: Just treat the initial list as two separate lists. And you will be fine.

Comment: @sobolevn I can't treat initial list, because this is synthetic data, for settings a way, real list have a lot of keys and I can't do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - Split the dictionary first, otherwise, it is not clear what is the logic to split them automatically. 
Step 2 - iterate through list of dictionaries and apply some if statements.
Here is what I think it should look like.  Hope I have got the logic behind thise right:

```
d = [{0: ['1', '2'], 1: '3', 2: '4'},
     {0: ['1', '2'], 1: '6', 2: '7'},
     {0: ['1111', '2222'], 1: '6', 2: '7'},
     {0: ['1111', '2222'], 1: '66', 2: '77'}
    ]

   #step 1
    def splitList(l, n):
        """
        takes list and positions to take from the list    
        """
        output = []
        for p in n:
            output.append(l[p])
        return output

    #step 2
    def orgDict(d):
        """
        modifies list of dictionaries into 1
        """
        d_output = {}    
        for d_ind in d:                
            for d_ind2 in d_ind:
                if (d_output.get(d_ind2) == None):
                    if (type(d_ind[d_ind2]) == list):
                        d_output[d_ind2] = d_ind[d_ind2]
                    else:
                        d_output[d_ind2] = [d_ind[d_ind2]]
                else:
                    if ((d_ind[d_ind2] not in d_output[d_ind2]) and (d_ind[d_ind2] != d_output[d_ind2])):
                        d_output[d_ind2].append(d_ind[d_ind2])
        return d_output

#tests
#expected output:
#{0: ['1', '2'], 1: ['3', '6'], 2: ['4', '7']}
print orgDict(splitList(d,[0,1]))

#expected output:
#{0: ['1111', '2222'], 1: ['6', '66'], 2: ['7', '77']}
print orgDict(splitList(d,[2,3]))
```